# swift peformSegue from child

Tags: xcode, swift, parent

**I have** a storyboard with a *Navigation Controller* hooked to 2 views, first one containing a *UIScrollView* which I have populated with several *ViewController*'s (ex Home, Profile, etc), and a second one containing a login screen

**I want to** be able to logout from one of the subviews/childs of the UIScrollView, one way I've tried is

Simplified code snippet:

```
 ContainerViewController
    ViewdidLoad()
    {
        self.addChildViewController(BVc);
    }
```

ChildViewController containing a logout button

```
 ChildViewController
     @IBAction func Loggout(sender: AnyObject)
     {
         performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: parent?)
     }
```

I hope I made myself clear, as It's my first post.

Comment: Segues are for moving between view controllers. Did you mean to say your Navigation Controller is linked to 2 View Controllers? If so, how are they linked?

Comment: @vrwim the UIScrollView/ContainerViewController is linked as root and from Container View Controller I have linked the Login page via a Segue, so I wonder I it's possible to access a parents segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you want to do is move back to earlier View Controller, am I right? If that's correct, you should access the View Controller's navigationController property. For example, if you want to go back in the *navigation stack*, you could pop the top view:

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

For more information, please take a look at UINavigationController Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/